# Chamar layouts dentro de um modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-datatables

Tenho uma aplicação pronta com layout próprio, e dentro deste layout eu uso o fancybox. Só que agora estou obrigado a migrar para o `bootstrap` e estou usando o *AdminLTE-2.1.1* por se encaixar no que eu quero.

A grande questão é migrar as partes com o *fancybox* para o modal. No fancybox era só declarar uma classe e dar opções do tamanho do `iframe` e abria a página independente, como mostro abaixo:

```
$(".detalhes").fancybox({
        closeBtn  : true,
            type: 'iframe',
            'autoSize': false,      
            'width': 600, 
            'height': 500
    });
```

Chamada do link:

```
<a class="detalhes fancybox.iframe" href="detalhes.php?id='.$row[7].'" >
<img src="imagens/atualiza.png" border=0 title="Ver detalhes "/>
</a>
```

Já com o modal do `bootstrap`, a página abre a partir da própria página, como segue abaixo:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="meumodal"]', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).attr("data-target");
  content = $(this).attr("href");
  $(target+".modal .modal-content").load(content,function(){
     $(target).modal('show');
  });
});
```

div do modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-toggle="meumodal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

chamada do link:

```
<a data-toggle="meumodal" href="detalhes.php?id='.$row[7].'" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-info" title="Ver detalhes">
<i class="fa fa-file-zip-o"></i>
</a>
```

div página externa:

```
<div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Detalhes Requerimento</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

CONTEÚDO


</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancelar</button>                    
</div>
```

ou seja, muito mais trabalhoso. Mas independente disso, eu prefiro pela migração, até porque ficaria um trabalho nada profissional.

Não existe nenhum outro plugin para `bootstrap` que chame a página independente com o layout do modal?

Nenhuma chamada jquery funciona no modal e estão exatamente como no fancybox.

Exemplo:

```
$(".curso").hide();
$(".local").hide();
$(".orgao").hide();

$('#tipo').on('change', function () {
    var valor = this.value;

    if(valor == 3){
    $(".curso").show();
    $(".local").show();
    $(".orgao").hide();
    }else if(valor == 2){
    $(".curso").hide();
    $(".local").show();
    $(".orgao").hide();     
    }else{
    $(".curso").hide();
    $(".local").hide();
    $(".orgao").show(); 
    }


});

    $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="mdModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">

   </div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

</div>
```

Ao que parece falta a div mãe onde dentro ficaram as divs header e footer

a chamada jquery $("mdModal").modal("show");

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode salvar os modais em arquivos separados. Carregue o conteúdo do modal chamando o id no outro documento:

**myModal.html**:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            Este modal foi extraído do arquivo myModal.html
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Janela modal de arquivo externo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    //Comportamento do <a> ao clicar
    $('#btn-modal').click(function () {
        //Pega o conteudo do arquivo myModal.html
        $.get("myModal.html", function (result) {
            //Coloca o conteudo de myModal.html no corpo do index.html
            $( "body" ).append( result);
            //Abre o modal 
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
    <br>
    <!--Aqui está a chamada do MODAL-->
    <a href='#' data-target="#myModal" class='btn btn-default' id="btn-modal">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;
            myModal
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui foi usada uma tag `<a>` com um link, mas vc também pode usar um `<button>` com um evento onclick, etc.

Comment: eu consigo fazer isso com um link dinâmico? pois uso muito o envio via get no php. na página myModal.html tenho que fazer chamada do jquery e do css?

Comment: Não sei bem o que é um "link dinâmico" segundo a sua perspectiva, mas editei a resposta pra mostrar que vc carrega as bibliotecas na HEAD do index.html, o **myModal.html** fica apenas com o conteúdo do modal.

Comment: desculpe a demora é que estava testando e acabei conseguindo fazer funcionar os jquerys dentro do modal apenas o jquery validate que não funciona de jeito nehum tem como me ajudar segue o link no jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/opeta/bLsvkeot/

Comment: Janelas modal não são propriamente "janelas". Janelas têm a capacidade de carregar as próprias bibliotecas para o documento, mas você não vai conseguir fazer um modal carregar bibliotecas independentes (como a jquery validate) porque ele depende do que foi declarado no HTML principal.